# Linq: Queryable.OrderBy() using a collection of Expressions

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, lambda

I wonder how I can store orderby expressions in a list. This is what I wanted to write:

```
List<Expression<Func<Products,Object>>> list = new List<Expression<Func<Products,Object>>>()
{
  p => p.Name,
  p => p.Id
};
```

Then:

```
var expr = list[0];
myProducts.OrderBy( expr );
```

which works for `p.Name`, but does not work for `p.Id` (`list[1]`) as it drops follwing exception

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll
>   Additional information: Unable to cast the type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Object'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types.

What type of list do I have to use?

Comment: A workaround is to write `p => p.Id.ToString()` but I would like to see it working with `System.Int32` as well

Comment: @RobertFricke that's not a workaround, it will also result with a NotSupportedException

Comment: @RobertFricke: If you order it as a string, the range from 1 to 12 would then be `1, 10, 11, 12, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9` which is not what you want.

Comment: Instead of Func<Product, object> try Func<Product, dynamic>

Comment: @RandRandom, that won't work either.

Comment: It changes the return type of myProducts.OrderBy(...) from IOrderedQueryable<T> to IOrderedEnumerable<T> :(

Comment: @haim770 would be nice to know why you think/know this won't work.

Comment: @RandRandom, because i tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my solution (using Reflection and based on [DynamicLinq](http://dynamiclinq.codeplex.com) ideas):

Defining a `ConvertableExpression` class so we can intercept calls to our custom `OrderBy()`:

```
public class ConvertableExpression<T>
{
    public ConvertableExpression(Expression<Func<T, object>> expr)
    {
        this.Expression = expr;
    }

    public Expression<Func<T, object>> Expression { get; private set; }
}
```

Introducing an Extension-Method for easier casting from normal `Expression`:

```
public static class ExpressionExtensions
{
    public static ConvertableExpression<T> AsConvertable<T>(this Expression<Func<T, object>> expr)
    {
        return new ConvertableExpression<T>(expr);
    }
}
```

Extending `IQueryable` with Reflection-based implementation of `OrderBy()`:

```
public static class QueryableExtensions
{
    public static IOrderedQueryable<T> OrderBy<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, ConvertableExpression<T> expr)
    {
        Expression queryExpr = source.Expression;

        var exprBody = SkipConverts(expr.Expression.Body);
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda(exprBody, expr.Expression.Parameters);
        var quote = Expression.Quote(lambda);

        queryExpr = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), "OrderBy", new[] { source.ElementType, exprBody.Type }, queryExpr, quote);

        return (IOrderedQueryable<T>)source.Provider.CreateQuery(queryExpr);
    }

    private static Expression SkipConverts(Expression expression)
    {
        Expression result = expression;

        while (result.NodeType == ExpressionType.Convert || result.NodeType == ExpressionType.ConvertChecked)
            result = ((UnaryExpression)result).Operand;

        return result;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
myProducts.OrderBy(expr.AsConvertable());
```

Comment: Why is "OrderBy" returns with an IQueryable instead of the expected IOrderedQueryable as the "original" OrderBy does? Should I cast it to this interface at the end?

Comment: You're right. I changed the method to return `IOrderedQueryable`.

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like the implementation of OrderBy for EF works by checking if *< T >* is a struct or object, and so you tell it to call *OrderBy<..., object >(someStructTypeVariable)*

As a workaround I would sugest you to store whole delegates instead of expresions.

Try this:

```
internal static class MyExtensions
{
    public static IOrderedQueryable<TSource> OrderBy<TSource, TField>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, Expression<Func<TSource, TField>> selector, bool descending)
    {
        return descending 
            ? source.OrderByDescending(selector)
            : source.OrderBy(selector);
    }

}


var orderers = new List<Func<IQueryable<Products>, IOrderedQueryable<Products>>>()
    {
        source => source.OrderBy(x => x.Id, true),
        source => source.OrderBy(x => x.Id, false), 
        source => source.OrderBy(x => x.Name, false)
    };


// To be replaced with entity source-collection.
IQueryable<Products> dummySource = new EnumerableQuery<MyType>(new List<Products>());

orderers[0](dummySource.Where(x => x.Id != 0));
```

Comment: Sorry, that is not a good solution for me :( as my expressions can be used either in an OrderBy or OrderByDescending, ThenBy, ThenByDescending as well.

Comment: Then write a wrapper method that will return orderby or orderby descending based on additional parameter. Be creative.

Comment: Trying to be creative, but cannot see your solution how works with a wrapper method - as your solution calls the OrderBy directly.

Comment: I've updated the example for you. Check if it works for you.
But i really don't know why do you use it. you could have create two collections: for ascending and descending.

Comment: The only other solution would be to get the right method by reflection.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
List<Func<Products, Object>> list = new List<Func<Products, Object>>()
{
    new Func<Products,Object>( p => p.Name),
    new Func<Products,Object>( p => p.Id),
};
```

Comment: Now we only need an explanation, why it does work as an `Expression` with a string, but not with an int32 type and hwo your soultion differs internally

Comment: Cannot see the difference between your solution and mine... what is the main point of view?

Comment: This solution will call Linq to Objects (`IEnumerable.OrderBy`) instead of Linq to Entities (`IQueryable.OrderBy`) and will not be translated into store-query (SQL in this case).